# ERROR TypeError: res[0].price.map is not a function in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, angular6

I'm trying to draw a line chart based on Rest data, but i get this error

> core.js:1521 ERROR TypeError: res[0].price.map is not a function
>       at SafeSubscriber._next (app.component.ts:26)
>       at

Here is the code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HelperService } from './helper.service';
import {Chart} from 'chart.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  chart = [];


  constructor(private _graph:HelperService){

  }

  ngOnInit(){


    this._graph.getGraphData()
        .subscribe(res => {
          console.log(res);

         let stock_price0 = res[0].price.map(res => res[0].price);
         let stock_price1 = res[1].price.map(res => res[1].price);

          let timeloop=[1,2,3,4,5,6];





         this.chart = new Chart('canvas',{
           type:'line',
           data: {
             labels:timeloop,
             datasets: [
               {
                 data:stock_price0,
                 borderColor:'#3cba9f',
                 fill:false
               },
               {
                data:stock_price1,
                borderColor:'#ffcc00',
                fill:false
              }
             ]
           },
           options:{
             legend:{
               display:false
             }
           }
         })

        })
  }
}
```

This is the json format,

> [{"id":1,"stockName":"A","price":5,"qty":10,"sector":"Finance"},{"id":2,"stockName":"B","price":3,"qty":2,"sector":"Tech"},{"id":3,"stockName":"C","price":4,"qty":1,"sector":"Gov"},{"id":4,"stockName":"Z","price":2,"qty":5,"sector":"Finance"},{"id":5,"stockName":"J","price":5,"qty":1,"sector":"Gov"},{"id":6,"stockName":"K","price":3,"qty":3,"sector":"Tech"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the JSON, res[0].price is not an array. its just a field. Map works over an array. I think you need

```
  let stock_price0 = res[0].price;
```

**EDIT**

I think you need price values into an array,

you can do this,

```
 let stock_price0 = res[0].map(res => res.price);
```

**DEMO**

```js
var myjson = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "stockName": "A",
    "price": 5,
    "qty": 10,
    "sector": "Finance"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "stockName": "B",
    "price": 3,
    "qty": 2,
    "sector": "Tech"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "stockName": "C",
    "price": 4,
    "qty": 1,
    "sector": "Gov"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "stockName": "Z",
    "price": 2,
    "qty": 5,
    "sector": "Finance"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "stockName": "J",
    "price": 5,
    "qty": 1,
    "sector": "Gov"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "stockName": "K",
    "price": 3,
    "qty": 3,
    "sector": "Tech"
  }
];
var result = myjson.map(a => a.price);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: but that doesn't draw the chart :/ the chart is empty, i think i need map somehow

Comment: is this format invalid?

[{"id":1,"stockName":"A","price":5,"qty":10,"sector":"Finance"},{"id":2,"stockName":"B","price":3,"qty":2,"sector":"Tech"},{"id":3,"stockName":"C","price":4,"qty":1,"sector":"Gov"},{"id":4,"stockName":"Z","price":2,"qty":5,"sector":"Finance"},{"id":5,"stockName":"J","price":5,"qty":1,"sector":"Gov"},{"id":6,"stockName":"K","price":3,"qty":3,"sector":"Tech"}]

Comment: you need to take all price into an array?

Comment: check the answer above

Comment: it didn't worked for me :/ , but you are correct though that's why i approved it. but id didn't worked

Comment: oh i figured it out in this morning, thanks for shownig me where to apply map() :)

Comment: @Sajeetharan-MSFT hi, you have suggestion for my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57834351/typeerror-this-receivedsummons-map-is-not-a-function-angular